# Tensorflow: create a 1D of non-fixed-length tensor of zeroes, and set one of its values to 1?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, training-data, tensor

I'm trying to create a simple ANN with Python and TensorFlow and I'm quite a newbie. 
I feel a bit embarrassed to ask such a basic thing, but I just don't find this in the official documentation, so here I am.

My training samples are events happening to people. 
Different events can happen to the same person, so my training samples must feature a "person" field.
Each person has an integer, auto-incrementing ID.

I guess that, building the training samples to pass to the NN, I need to represent the 'person' field as a 1D tensor with:

- 1 in the person.id position
- 0 elsewhere (I guess this means I must use `tf.zeroes()`, right?)

And here comes the question.
The amount of people in my DB may frequently change and I don't really want to re-train my network every time I add a new person. So I think I should not create the 1D tensor passing it the current amount of people in the DB.

What I'd like to do is building a **1D zeroes tensor of non fixed length**, and just set its value in person.id as 1.

Is it possible? Is it the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating a network architecture that can process data with dynamic size is not a trivial task. For example, it is possible by using spacial pooling layers or by using fully convolutional networks. Maybe a simpler solution can be found for your problem. What exactly is the input and the expected output of your network? Are the events part of the input or the output? Should the network learn some behavior of individual people? If that is the case, how do you expect the network to process newly added people without some kind of additional training/re-training?

Comment: why not make one iteration, find the max length, and pad every vector to this max length with zeros?

Comment: I was thinking to use the NN to guess tennis sport matches results.   
So an event is a single match, and a person is a tennis player.

So events (played matches) are definitely part of the input, and I think that the network should learn the behaviour of individual players.
When adding new players, I'd like to perform additional training on the new data without need to retrain from scratch.

Comment: You're probably better off retraining, but, a simple solution would be to  start with a vector that leaves room for growth. If you have 100 players in your database today, create a vector of 150 then you can grow by 50 until you need to fully retrain. Another option is to pre-process your users by clustering them into a fixed set of player types, then use that fixed set of clusters as your input, that way new players simply get clustered to one of the existing groups.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll probably use a vector that leaves room for growth as you suggested :) 

However, I see that tensors in tensorflow can actually have non fixed length (even though I still haven't figured out how to create a 1D non fixed length vector).
Now I don't think that non fixed length can be useful in the sense I meant in my question. However, I was wondering when it can be useful then.

Comment: You can use a tensor of non fixed length, but you will have to use TensorFlow Fold, which is quite new and a bit more complicated than regular TensorFlow if you ask me. But take a look! https://research.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-tensorflow-fold-deep.html

Comment: Wow, I completely ignored the existence of TensorFlow Fold.
Thanks for the advice Wolf Vos!